# Quarkus - KStream and KTable join does not output messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, quarkus

I am building a project modeled on [this project](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams). The key difference is, I want to output, conditionally, a message using the messages from the joined topics. As opposed to the example project, where an aggregation is performed. I am struggling to use `Serde` for JSON messages and so, I have simplified the message structure as follows.

- `t1` (`KStream`) - a plain text value.
- `t2` (`KTable`) - a plain text value separated by a `;`.
- `t3` (`KStream`) - a CSV string.

I am publishing messages using `kafkacat` with the `-k` option to set a key e.g. `k1`. The problem I am facing is: I don't see any output in `t3`.

This is my `TopologyProducer.java`.

```java
@Produces
  public Topology buildTopology() {
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    ObjectMapperSerde<stream1> stream1 = new ObjectMapperSerde<>(stream1.class);
    ObjectMapperSerde<topic1> topic1 = new ObjectMapperSerde<>(topic1.class);
    ObjectMapperSerde<output1> output1 = new ObjectMapperSerde<>(output1.class);

    GlobalKTable<String, topic1> topic1 = builder.globalTable(
        t2,
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), topic1));

    builder.stream(t1,
        Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), stream1))
        .join(t2,
            (paramName, paramValue) -> paramName,
            (paramValue, paramLimits) -> {
              // Add some logic to return conditionally
              return new output1("paramName", 0.0, 0.0, true);
            })
        .to(t3,
            Produced.with(Serdes.String(), output1));
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java version I had in my `Dockerfile` was wrong.

When I inspected the container logs, I saw an error about the difference in version of Java used to compile (higher) vs running (lower). I chose the simpler of two i.e. used a more recent version of Java to run the application (than, adjusting the Java version for local `mvn` build). The error can be traced to the following instruction as documented [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka-streams#building-and-running-the-applications).

> The `Dockerfile` created by Quarkus by default needs one adjustment for the aggregator application in order to run the Kafka Streams pipeline. To do so, edit the file `aggregator/src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm` and replace the line `FROM fabric8/java-alpine-openjdk8-jre` with `FROM fabric8/java-centos-openjdk8-jdk`.

I edited my `Dockerfile` to use `FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.11` and have the application running.